# Unicode text excel python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

my parse is russain text excel, I use xlrd

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import cx_Oracle
import csv
import xlrd
loc = ("parse.xls")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc, encoding_override="cp1251") 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 
print(sheet.row_values(4))
```

I have a problem russian text, my result:

> [u'\u041a\u0430\u0440-\u0422\u0435\u043b ', u'\u0421\u0443\u0449', u'44061AKBAKAY', 1.0, u'']

excel:
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Grismar problem russian text

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 displays list contents as a debug representation using `repr()`.  Print individual items to view in printing representation using `str()`, but this can still fail if the terminal code page and font both do not support Cyrillic:

```
>>> items = [u'\u041a\u0430\u0440-\u0422\u0435\u043b ', u'\u0421\u0443\u0449', u'44061AKBAKAY', 1.0, u'']
>>> items
[u'\u041a\u0430\u0440-\u0422\u0435\u043b ', u'\u0421\u0443\u0449', u'44061AKBAKAY', 1.0, u'']
>>> for item in items:
...  print(item)
...
Кар-Тел
Сущ
44061AKBAKAY
1.0
```

Switch to Python 3, which is better at displaying Unicode strings and (at least on Windows) doesn't care about the terminal code page.  The font still has to support Cyrillic:

```
>>> items = [u'\u041a\u0430\u0440-\u0422\u0435\u043b ', u'\u0421\u0443\u0449', u'44061AKBAKAY', 1.0, u'']
>>> items
['Кар-Тел ', 'Сущ', '44061AKBAKAY', 1.0, '']
```